# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path

Tags: c#, sql, null, localdb

I'm working with a local dataBase in a Windows Form Application and I'm trying to implement the source for the dataBase as DataDirectory, so in case I'm moving the db from one computer to another, it will work just fine. I wrote the following code, but I get this error, that the value cannot be null, at the line where it gets the Fullpath. Thanks !

```
var dataDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataDirectory"];
var absoluteDataDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(dataDirectory);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absoluteDataDirectory);
var connString = (@"Data Source= |DataDirectory|\Angajati.sdf");
```

Comment: Look at the error just for a moment. It is already telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you get it from connection string section inside your app.config?

Comment: I know what the error tells. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: check manually if the path exist

Comment: looks like it doesn't .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this section in your `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DataDirectory" value="DataDirectoryPath"/>
</appSettings>
```

By the way for accessing DataDirectory you have to use this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")
```

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266924/how-do-i-read-the-current-path-of-datadirectory-from-config-settings).

Comment: Works. Shows that the path is correct, but it doesn't insert in the db. I mean. It goes till the /Debug but then enter a folder named DataDirectoryPath. why?