# C# local database not updating when using |DataDirectory|

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am using a local database and for some reason when I use `|DataDirectory|`, the database doesn't update when I add/delete

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");  
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

**BUT** if I use the following directory it does work

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\Project\Home_Database\HomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");  
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Anyone may know why?

Comment: Are you assuming that the value of `|DataDirectory|` is the same as `F:\Project\Home_Database\` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, i read that I can use that to get my project directory

Comment: Did you check what value the `|DataDirectory|` has? Are  you changing it in your code or some where to have value `F:\Project\Home_Database` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No i just assumed I could use |DataDirectory| instead of `F:\Project\Home_Database`

Comment: `|DataDirectory|` does have value specific to the current running application. So you can not just assume that you could use it in place of any path. You can first explore about `DataDirectory` and understand it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266924/how-do-i-read-the-current-path-of-datadirectory-from-config-settings) and [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I read that, doesn't help me understand why it isnt working. This article says |DataDirectory| can replace my current path, but it doesnt work

Comment: F:\Project\Home_Database this is my current path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|DataDirectory|` variable has a value set by the .NET Framework based on the OS.

I did a quick experiment with this as following.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");

        Console.WriteLine(dataDirectory);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I ran above code, it displayed nothing. Upon debugging I figured that the `dataDirectory` variable has value `null`.

Then I tried to use it to create database connection and open it.

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

 conn.Open();
```

This code failed at `conn.Open();` with following error.

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Chetan\Sandbox\consoleapp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\HomeDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

As you can see from the error that, because '`|DataDirectory|` is null, the application tries to locate the `.mdf` file at `bin\Debug` folder under the project directory which is basically the location from where the exe is running.

So if you want the `|DataDirectory|` have different value, you first need to change it before using it. As following.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");

        //Changing DataDirectory value.
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "C:\\DataFiles");

        Console.WriteLine(dataDirectory);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        conn.Open();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

With this code, I noticed that the value `"C:\\DataFiles"` was used to locate `HomeDB.mdf`.

If you read [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/) it explains the order in which values of `|DataDirectory|` are expanded.

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/07/25/customizing-the-connection-string-for-tableadapters/) explains about how to customize the value of `|DataDirectory|`.

Now coming to your issue of data not being reflected.

In your case, `|DataDirectory|` has null value, so it is connecting to the `HomeDB.mdf` file located at the `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder making changes there while you are looking at `F:\Project\Home_Database\HomeDB.mdf` to verify the changes.

You are not seeing the error which I am seeing because the .mdf file is copied to the executable location when you are building the project.

So solution to your problem is to change the value of `|DataDirectory|` using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",<<yourvalue>>);` method.

**EDIT:**

If the location of `.mdf` file is fix relative to the executable file of the project, you can build the value for `|DataDirectory|` at runtime and assign it.

Let say, you have a folder `Database` at the same location as the `exe` and `Database` folder has `HomeDB.mdf` file. So first you need to find the path from where the `exe` is running and append `Database` to is and assign it to `|DataDirectory|`.

```
//Get the current path from where the exe is running.
var currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

//Build path to Database folder
var databasePath = currentDirectory + "Database";

//Assign it to DataDirectory
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", databasePath);

var dataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");

Console.WriteLine(dataDirectory);

//Use DataDirectory to SQL Connection.
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HomeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

conn.Open();
```

This would work without any issue no matter from where you are running the application. It will work as long as you have `Database` folder and `HomeDB.mdf` file in that folder.

**EDIT END**

You also might want to consider putting the connection string in the configuration file, instead of hard-coding it into the code itself.

I hope I was able to explain the point clearly and this would help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: So I would need to change the value of |DataDirectory| everytime I move the folder from my computer to my USB?

Comment: I have updated the answer including the solution of scenario you mentioned. With that solution you don't need to change anything when you move the application folder anywhere. Read [this](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/6-ways-to-get-the-current-directory-in-csharp/) too