# Why the created .exe can't run/open? c# winforms application

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms, linq

Everyone I have created a .exe file with localdb and that db file pos.mdf is include in winforms application and I use local db connection string like(`connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Data\POS.mdf; Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=True"`) and I use linq in my app and I created .exe of my app successfully through Visual Studio Installer, but the problem is after successfully installation my pos app can't be run/open I don't know why and what's the problem with my app.
Visual Studio 2017.
Sql Server 2014.
please help me to correct it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check any logs in eventvwr.msc?

Comment: [SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017). Just in case, take a look at the last paragraph first (Permissions). This decription may also help: [local database not updating when using |DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53643907/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\Data\POS.mdf; Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=True"

change to

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|
Data\POS.mdf; Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=True"