# SQL Server database not updating after using |DataDirectory| in C# Windows Form project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows

I've made connection string in app.config and used it whenever I needed to make a SQL connection using this code:

```
static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString;
```

It works perfectly if I use full path to the database but I want to make it universal (so I could install my application on any other PC) and I used `|DataDirectory|` like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Biblioteka.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

After using `|DataDirectory|`, I can access the database (I'm not getting any errors while debugging) through my app but I cannot update it, delete records from tables etc...

Is there a way I can keep using app.config for connection string and making it universal at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update |DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266924/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why saving changes to a database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)

Answer (score 0):

`|DataDirectory|` can resolve to many different things depending on your application and how it is installed, but typically it is a read-only folder shared among all users which you **should not change**. Moreover, repairing or uninstalling your app will typically overwrite or erase `|DataDirectory|`, so even if you could update it your updates would soon be deleted.

`|DataDirectory|` is a good location for data which must not change, or for a source or seed database for your applications. If you want users to update data, you should copy the data from `|DataDirectory|` to the user data folder, that location is writeable and does not get overwritten or deleted, then make all user changes to the copy.

For more information read [How do I update `|DataDirectory|`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266924/).